# Как избежать повторения чисел при использовании рандома?

Tags: delphi

Есть прога которая из `memo1` (его содержания) выводит в `Edit1`, по средствам нажатия `Button1`, рандомно слова, как сделать чтобы после вывода слова оно больше не появлялось? Прошу всё изложить подробно.

```
var
  vorname : string;
begin
  vorname := memo1.Lines[random(memo1.Lines.Count) + 1];
  edit1.Text := vorname + ' ';
end;
```

Comment: Самое очевидное, например, удаляйте слово из `memo1`.

Comment: Подробно вам придется излагать курс дискретной математики, дабы объяснить что есть линейный конгруэнтный генератор псевдослучайных чисел, каковы его свойства и так далее.

Comment: Надо заново инициализировать генератор (плевдо)случайных чисел. Обычно это делается текущем датой (дата как число). А как это в делфях сделано уже вам искать :)

В борланде инициализация вызывалась с помощью функции randomize()

Comment: @gil9red Не верно. Ре-инициализация ГСЧ не предотвратит повторного появления числа.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вопрос куда проще и никакой курс читать не надо.

Comment: @KromStern смотря каким число инициализировать. Если текущей датой, то оно каждый момент времени будет другим числом инициализироваться, а то что генерируемые рандомные числа **никогда** не будут повторяться никто не будет гарантировать

Comment: @gil9red о том и речь, что данный совет к этому вопросу не относится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое - удалять использованные слова:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  vorname: string;
begin
  i := random(memo1.Lines.Count); // Даст значение от 0 до Count-1
  vorname := memo1.Lines[i]; // Берем слово из соответствующей строки
  edit1.Text := vorname + ' ';
  memo1.Lines.Delete(i); // Удаляем строку со словом из "справочника"
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ, то что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Есть два способа не повторять уже использованные случайные значения.

1. Запоминать все использованные значения в массиве и для каждого нового случайного значения проверять, есть ли оно в массиве или нет.
2. Если можно использовать не очень большой диапазон случайных чисел `[0, D-1]`, то:
   ~ задать массив со значениями от `0` до `D-1`;
   ~ датчик случайных чисел должен генерировать индекс в этом массиве;
   ~ после использования числа из массива записывать на его место последний элемент массива, а диапазон генерируемых индексов `D` уменьшать на единицу.

Answer (score 0):

Более универсальное решение -- TDictionary. http://keeper89.blogspot.com/2011/07/delphi-2.html (храним пару "слово"-"число употреблений" или "номер строки"-"число употреблений").

Заводим словарь. Через random берем слово. Проверяем наличие его с словаре. При добавлении слова добавляем слово в словарь. А если слово в словаре есть, то добавляем +1 к значению.

В этом случае, когда закончатся все слова мы сможем добавлять слова дальше, только вместо сравнения с "0", будем сравнивать с "1".